# Saving Webpage With Javascript/jQuery Changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was curious if there is a way for users to save a complete webpage after changes have been made via Javascript/jQuery.  To my understanding this is only possible with server side coding - but I was unable to find a definitive answer.

As a simple example, I would allow users the ability to customize something like the background color and text of a webpage, and then save their changes to their local machine.

Edit: The resources I'm looking to create will need to be saved to their local machine as a webpage - therefore storing information in the browser is not ideal.

The resources will be used for a program called OBS, where the user will basically be importing the saved elements via the locally saved file.

Comment: "save their changes to their local machine" so that when they come back to your page, the changes are saved or that they can have a copy of the html page, with their changes ?

Comment: You should be more descriptive. Do you want temporary or permanent storage? Do you want to save the html page or its content or the user made customizations only?

Comment: I want to save the entire page, with the edits made to it.  When I say "save locally" I mean the users will literally be saving the webpage files to their hard drive.  I tried to add more information via my edit.

Comment: @Kaiido so they can save a copy of the page with their changes.

Answer (score 3):

On [modern Browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Blob#Browser_compatibility), you can use an [XMLSerializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/XMLSerializer) and [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Blob) to achieve it :

```js
document.querySelector('input').onchange = function() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = this.value;
}

document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  // serialize the whole document as a string
  var doc = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document.documentElement);
  // convert this string to a blob object
  if (window.Blob) {
    var blob = new Blob([doc], {type: 'text/html'});
    // create a blob URL
    a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  } else
  //browser don't support Blob object, create a data url
    a.href = 'data: text/html; charset=utf8, ' + doc;
  
  
  /* The following won't work in the snippet but can be used on your server for browsers supporting download attribute

    if ('download' in a) {
      a.download = 'yourPageName.html';
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.click();
      document.body.removeChild(a);
    } else {*/
  a.innerHTML = 'Right click - Save As.. to download the page';
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  //  }
}
```

```html
Hello
<input placeholder="choose a background color" />
<button>save</button>
```

Comment: is there any way to hide some content on downloaded html page?

Answer (score 2):

It's *better* to store those settings server side associated with the user itself, so the settings are saved and can be seen in different browsers/ devices, and won't get deleted clearing browser storage.

Anyways, as it's already stated it *can* be done using the browser local storage

Comment: I apologize for not being more clear in the beginning, but the issue is that for what I'd like to create, users will be unable to take advantage of local storage via the browser.  In essence, I'd like to have them be able to make changes via jQuery/JS and then right click the webpage and "Save As".

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Cookies`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie), [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) or [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Cookies and localStorage can persist through different sessions, sessionStorage only persists until the browser is closed. From the [`MDN Web Storage API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API)

> - sessionStorage maintains a separate storage area for each given origin that's available for the duration of the page session (as long as the browser is open, including page reloads and restores)
> - localStorage does the same thing, but persists even when the browser is closed and reopened.